# Illegal offset type when i create a new row on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, laravel-8

We created three tables called 'users', 'corso', 'iscrizione' is a middle table between users and corso, it has two attributes that are PK/FK.
 We successfully built the methods to create/update/read/delete rows inside 'corso' and we populated manually 'users'.
 We are trying to realize a create method for iscrizione but when we tried to execute it with Postman it generates this error:

```
ErrorException: Illegal offset type in file I:\Test db Laravel\testdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php on line 1146

 Illegal offset type
```

These are the Class Models of each tables on the database:

Iscrizione Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Iscrizione extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $hidden = ['idCorso', 'idUtente'];
    protected $primaryKey = ['idCorso', 'idUtente'];
    protected $table = 'iscrizione';
}
```

Corso Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Corso extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'idCorso';
    protected $table = 'corso';
    protected $fillable = ['tipo','nome', 'membriMax', 'inizio', 'fine'];
}
```

The last one is the creation method on our ApiController Class:

```
public function iscrizione(Request $request){
        
        $iscrizione = new Iscrizione();

        $iscrizione->idCorso = $request->input('idCorso');
        $iscrizione->idUtente = $request->input('idUtente');

        $iscrizione->save();
        return response()->json($iscrizione);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the setKeysForSaveQuery to use the composite keys you have defined for the Iscrizione model:

**Iscrizione.php**

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    return $query->where('idCorso', $this->getAttribute('idCorso'))
        ->where('idUtente', $this->getAttribute('idUtente'));
}
```

and also remove the following line

```
protected $primaryKey = ['idCorso', 'idUtente'];
```

Comment: It gives me this error while adding into Iscrizione.php Model: `Method setKeysForSaveQuery is not compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery()`.

Comment: Did you import Builder by using use statement?

Comment: Yes We did. We imported `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;`

Comment: Then may be there is some function signature mismatch issue. Which version you were working on?

Comment: We are working on Laravel  Framework 8.30.1

Comment: Check this issue may help out https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/34643

Comment: I think you should use "\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder" i.e use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Comment: We figured out that we need to create HasCompositePrimaryKey.php Trait the problem is we don't know how to add this specific trait. Is the only way to make Eloquent model support the composite keys. We imported also \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder and still the same error

Comment: As they(laravel community) mention that they have already solved the issue in the newer version. try by updating the laravel version

Comment: What is the latest version of Laravel 8? I supposed that 8.31.0 was the latest already. We tried also to run `composer update`